# Android save image to file and use ExifInterface to extract meta data

Tags: android, image, camera, imageview, exif

I am having trouble trying to save an image taken by the camera and stored into the `ImageView` variable `ImageBox`. I am trying to save the image as 'Pic.jpg' and then using the `ExifInterface`class, I would like to extract meta data from the image `Pic.jpg`and display its `TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF` and `TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF` into the `TextView` variables `LongitudeBox`and `LatitudeBox`. So far the application does load up fine and lets you take an image and displays the image into the `ImageView ImageBox` variable but! it does not display anything in either the `LongitudeBox` or `LatitudeBox` so I am not sure if it is unable to find the image or it cannot extract the data. Please help me find what's wrong within my code. Thank you!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    //variables
    Button CameraButton;
    ImageView ImageBox;
    TextView LatitudeBox, LongitudeBox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CameraButton);
        ImageBox = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        LatitudeBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LatitudeBox);
        LongitudeBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LongitudeBox);

        //Camera Button Onclick
        CameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pic.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
                Uri output=Uri.fromFile(photo);
                String IMG = "Pic.jpg";

                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                try {
                    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(IMG);
                    LongitudeBox.setText(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF)); // get longitude
                    LatitudeBox.setText(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF)); //get latitude 

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }// try catch 
            }// end onclick 
        });// end camera button onclick





    }// close oncreate

    //display image inside ImageBox variable using bitmap
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if(requestCode == 0)
        {
        Bitmap TheImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageBox.setImageBitmap(TheImage);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }







}// close main
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to get the location(latitude and longitude) of the picture using the metadata? Just use the location providers in Android.  [Here is the official documentation along with some code.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)

If you scroll down to the "Tagging user-created content with a location" section you'll get some helpful advice.

Let me know how it goes. Cheers